# Regular Expression to move beginning of string to end in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++, replace

I have a textfile like so:

```
marc_webber
john_grisham
rahmin_darfur
firstname_lastname
```

I want the output to be like this (forget about double names like "van These"):

```
Webber, Marc, marc_webber
Grisham, John, john_grisham
Darfur, Rahmin, rahmin_darfur
LastName, FirstName, firstname_lastname
```

So I want to split the strings at the **_**, move the last name to the beginning and comma delimit first name and the concatenated name to the end (and maybe even capitalize the first letter).
This would be fairly easy with a programming language, but I want to know whether it is possible using **Notepad++'s find and replace feature with regular expressions**.
Basically I would need to create variables for the first name and the last name and string them together again in the end.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Except for the casing this should work (Tested in Programmers Notepad though...):

**Find Pattern:**

```
((\w+)_(\w+))
```

**Replace Pattern:**

```
\3, \2, \1
```

Comment: Doesn't your editor support \0 for the whole match? If yes you can avoid the first group

Comment: @fge: Does not work in programmers notepad. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: The replacement should be `\3, \2, \1`. You won't be able to change the case of any of the letters, though.

Comment: Thanks! I kind of get the casing right via TextFX > Characters > Proper Case, but case is not that important

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me using `sed` (I guess it also works in notepad++ since it probably supports perl regular expressions):

```
$ sed -r 's/(\w+)_(\w+)/\u\2, \u\1, \0/' file.txt
Webber, Marc, marc_webber
Grisham, John, john_grisham
Darfur, Rahmin, rahmin_darfur
Lastname, Firstname, firstname_lastname
```

The trick to get the capitalization as in your example is to use `\u`.

You can find more information about escape sequences [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreref.html).

Comment: Notepad++ doesn't support `\u` so you're pretty much stuck with the lowercase letters, and it doesn't support `\0` either so you'll have to capture the whole thing as well.